# insertar valor select html en sql

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, select

estoy intentando enviar el valor de un select html ( que se carga con valores de una Sql ) por php e insertar el valor en otra tabla.

Todo ello lo envio con ajax, pero a la hora de insertar los datos, en lugar del valor seleccionado, me inserta el ID del select.
pero hice un alert hacia la variable donde se almacena el resultado y en ella si que sale el valor seleccionado, no comprendo porque luego el php recibe el id.

el codigo es:

```
    <select id="movimiento" name="movimiento" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="">-- SELECCIONA --</option>
<?php foreach($movimiento as $f):?>
      <option value="<?php echo $f->id; ?>"><?php echo $f->Movimiento; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    $(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

 

  var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
  var correo = $('#correo').val();
  var usuario = $('#usuario').val();
  var clave = $('#clave').val();
  var movimiento = $('#movimiento option:selected').html();
  var extension = $('#user_image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  if(extension != '')
  {
   if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)
   {
    alert("imagen no valida");
    $('#user_image').val('');
    return false;
   }
  } 
  if(correo != '' && usuario != '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:'POST',
    data:new FormData(this),
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success:function(data)
    {
     alert(data);
     $('#user_form')[0].reset();
     $('#userModal').modal('hide');
     dataTable.ajax.reload();
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Todos los campos son obligatorios");
  }
 });

    if(isset($_POST["operation"]))
{
 if($_POST["operation"] == "Add")
 $variable=$_POST['movimiento'];
 {
  $image = '';
  if($_FILES["user_image"]["name"] != '')
  {
   $image = upload_image();
  }
  $statement = $connection->prepare("
   INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, correo, usuario, clave, movimiento, image) 
   VALUES (:nombre, :correo, :usuario, md5(:clave), :movimiento, :image)
  ");
  $result = $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':nombre' => $_POST["nombre"],
    ':correo' => $_POST["correo"],
    ':usuario' => $_POST["usuario"],
    ':clave' => $_POST["clave"],
    ':movimiento' => $_POST["movimiento"],
    ':image'  => $image
    
   )
  );
  if(!empty($result))
  {
   echo 'Usuario Creado';
  }
```

Alguien entiende donde puedo tener el problema? en el php quizas?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El valor que recibe el php es el que está en *value=""*. Si he entendido bien lo que necesitas, quedaría correcto de la siguiente manera:

```
<option value="<?php echo $f->Movimiento; ?>"></option>
```

Espero tu respuesta de si es lo que necesitabas.

Comment: Buenasen efecto eso lo había probado y funciona, el problema es que después en otro apartado utilizaré select dependientes, que al cambiar habilitan las opciones del siguiente select, por lo que utilice <option value="<?php echo $f->id; ?>"><?php echo $f->Movimiento; ?></option> para seleccionar el ID